# SSH session does not get terminated with cpp reboot comand

Tags: linux, debian, ssh, embedded, cpp

I have a small cpp application which will reboot the system. This works very well so far.

```
sync(); //need for data safety
reboot(RB_AUTOBOOT);
```

Unless you are connected via SSH and run this program on the connected device. Then the SSH connection hangs.

If you are connected via SSH and use the CLI commands

```
sudo reboot
```

or

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

The SSH connection will be terminated with the following message

```
Connection to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx closed by remote host.
Connection to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx closed.
```

How do I get the same behaviour with the cpp reboot method?

I read https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/reboot.2.html and search the internet, but didn't found something about this topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Solution is to use `kill(1, SIGINT)` instead of `reboot(RB_AUTOBOOT)`

More details in https://stackoverflow.com/a/69042761/6729765

Answer (score 0):

You must learn the difference between a "kernel reboot" and an "OS reboot":

The kernel reboot most likely just flushes the disk buffers and then resets, while the OS reboot will (try to) terminate all processes.

Sshd when being killed, will actively end all existing connections, so the client will be informed.
If the other side (server) is just being reset, the client end won't notice (well, PuTTY seems to notice shortly after pressing any key (that cannot be delivered)).